# How to make sure some C# code would compile?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to include some sort of automated code checking into our git-related pull-request workflow. I don't need full blown compile output because it takes too long for my needs, but it'd be nice if I could quickly just check to make sure the code *would* compile.

Is there a way to check some C# code for static analysis to make sure it'd compile? I don't see anything in msbuild for this.

Comment: I don't think that exists, but C# is (compared e.g. to C++) very fast to compile, what time frame are we talking about here?

Comment: Here is the contradiction, if you don't compile how do you make sure it would compile?

Comment: You cannot have the cake _and_ eat it.

Comment: I have plenty of ways to shut the compiler up and make it compile something without me actually writing code that makes any sense. Even if you could do what you wanted, it says nothing about the *quality* of the code you're letting through, let alone the semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for a simple *syntax check*. You could do this via Visual Studios command line comiler `csc.exe`.

```
csc /t:module file.cs
```

By using the compiler option `/t:` in conjunction with the `module` parameter the file is compiled as a module, not as an assembly. The former does not contain the manifest.

Your github actions script should then contain something like

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened]
jobs:
  build:
   -name: Syntax check
    run: 
      for file in $(find . -name "*.cs" -type f); do
        csc /t:module $file || exit 1
      done;
```

Comment: This might be close enough for OP's needs, but it's worth mentioning that there are other ways a codebase might fail to compile than just syntactic errors.